# Is there a PDF generation library similar to http://prawnpdf.org/

Tags: pdf-generation, crystal-lang

I am looking for the ability to generate PDFs in a similar manner to Prawnpdf using Crystal language.   Is there such a library, or is there a way for me to call into ruby code (like a ruby binding)?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything created yet for PDF generation in Crystal. Could you elaborate on your use case a little bit? 

To those voting to close, this is not really an opinionated question, as it's looking for any tool for an emerging language.

Comment: Not that I know of, but I'd consider binding to a C library that either generates PDF or converts it from an easier format, such as http://wkhtmltopdf.org/libwkhtmltox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually NO pdf generation library for Crystal..

But if you have the time, there are libraries which has a C/C++ interface that you could use to ***create*** a pdf generation lib :

- [JagToPdf](http://www.jagpdf.org/) : [Exemple](http://www.jagpdf.org/doc/jagpdf/usersguide/quick_start.htm#jagpdf.usersguide.quick_start.hello_world.c) in C (Full user guide [here](http://www.jagpdf.org/doc/jagpdf/usersguide.htm))
- [libHaru](http://libharu.org/) : It is written entirely in C, so interfacing with Crystal should not be difficult. [Exemple Usage here](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Usage-examples)